# Kubernetes hornetq issue

Tags: kubernetes, hornetq

I have dockerized a hornetq server that receives/serves data from 60 queues and 20 topics. While as a docker plays perfectly, as a kubernetes deployment there are problems after 2-3 hours.
Logs on deployment have no errors. What happens is that client healthcheck timeouts and marks it as unhealthy. Has anyone any idea of how I can debug or what's going on?

Comment: You should check if pods are not being restarted and the logs on them. Check [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/) docs describing how to troubleshoot k8s. You need to provide more details and logs for us to help.

Comment: No restarts at pods, no log errors. Just client healthcheck timeouts and marks it as unhealthy. I note that both cases are tested on the same machine.

Comment: What exactly is the "client healthcheck" doing from the broker's perspective? What specifically times out?

Comment: It's a custom health check mechanism that pings server every 30s.

Comment: Can you post the yaml of the pod with healthcheck?